# 誤訳: 「投稿数」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

ユーザの情報を表示するページで、「アクティビティ」の「行動履歴」の中に「投稿数」というタブがあります。

本家の方を見たところ posts となっているので、「投稿」の間違いではないでしょうか。また、このタブをクリックして表示される「xx件の投稿数」も「xx件の投稿」だと思います。

[image: 「投稿数」が使われている箇所]

細かいですが、しばらく意味が解らなかったので、修正をお願いできればと思います。

Comment: これを修正するためには、 [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja) から該当する文字列を見付けだして、翻訳を修正する必要があり、それがちょっと大変かもな、と思っている状態です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

翻訳を「投稿数」から「投稿」に修正しました。